# hide and show ActionLink and save data in database - MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am working on a MVC application and I have to turn labels into textboxes when user clicks `Edit` which is working fine but after clicking `Edit` and showing the textboxes `Edit` should hide and `Save` should appear and on clicking `Save` data should be save in database and should be refreshed on page.
But `Edit` ActionLink isn't hiding and `Save` ActionLink isn't appearing. and edited data is also not saving in database.

jQuery Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('a.Edit').click(function () {
                var dad = $(this).parent().parent();
                $('a.edit').hide();
                $('a.save').show();
                dad.find('.displaytext').hide();
                dad.find('input[type="text"]').show();
            });

        $('a.Save').click(function() {
            var dad = $(this).parent();
            //$(this).hide();
            $('a.edit').show();
            $('a.save').hide();
            dad.find('.displaytext').show();
            url = $(this).attr('href');
            $(this).load(url);
        });
        });
    </script>
```

HTML Code:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            @*<th>
                @Html.Label("ID")
            </th>*@
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Name")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Description")
            </th>
            <th>
                 @Html.Label("Date")
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (Convert.ToDateTime(item.Holiday_date).Year.ToString() == DateTime.Now.Year.ToString())
        {
            <tr>
           @* <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Id, new { style = "display: none; width:170px; height:15px" })
                <div class="displaytext">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Id)
                </div>
            </td>*@
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Name, new { style = "display: none; width:170px; height:15px" })
                <div class="displaytext">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Name)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Description, new { style = "display: none; width:170px; height:15px" })
                <div class="displaytext">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Description)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_date, new { style = "display: none; width:170px; height:15px" })
                <div class="displaytext">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_date)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
               @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Holiday_Id }, new { @class = "Edit", Href="#" })
               @Html.ActionLink("Save", "Save", new { id = item.Holiday_Id}, new { @class = "Save", Href = "#", style = "display:none" } ) |
               @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Holiday_Id }, new { @class = "lnkDelete" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        }

    }

    </table>
```

Controller Code:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            tbl_HolidayList tbl_holidaylist = db.tbl_HolidayList.Find(id);
            if (tbl_holidaylist == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return PartialView(tbl_holidaylist);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Holiday/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(tbl_HolidayList tbl_holidaylist)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(tbl_holidaylist).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                TempData["Msg"] = "Data has been updated succeessfully";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return PartialView(tbl_holidaylist);
        }
```

can anyone tell me my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html classes are case sensitive and you are using uppercase names for your classes.

Instead of:

```
$('a.edit').hide();
$('a.save').show();
```

use:

```
$('a.Edit').hide();
$('a.Save').show();
```

You can also consolidate a lot of the duplication in your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    function toggleEditability() {
        $(this).closest('tr')
               .find('a.Edit, a.Save, .displayText, input[type=text]')
               .toggle();
    }

    $('a.Edit').click(toggleEditability);

    $('a.Save').click(function() {
        toggleEditability.call(this);
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).load(url);
    });
});
```

Comment: you are right, I made these changes but now the whole `Edit` column turn into `Save` while just the specific row should change, and when I click save the row remains textboxes, they should become edited labels

Comment: and your updated answer turns all records into texboxes, I mean textbox appear on every record and labels are still there also

Comment: Pass ``toggleEditability()`` current clicked element reference using ``toggleEditability(this)`` and in method  ``function toggleEditability(element) {
        $(element).closest("tr").find('a.Edit, a.Save, .displayText, input[type=text]').toggle();
    }``  Now this will toggle just current row

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Thanks. I hadn't noticed that there was a table involved.

Comment: thank you, now `save/edit` works fine but edited data isn't saving in database

Comment: @Umm E Habiba Siddiqui debug to get to the problem

Comment: I can't see my `url` while debugging

Comment: @UmmEHabibaSiddiqui use firebug tool or chrome dev tools

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it may just be an issue with the case of your jquery selectors.  You classes are defined with the first character in upper case yet in your selector you are querying for it with lower case first letter.

Comment: you are right, I made these changes but now the whole Edit column turn into Save while just the specific row should change, and when I click save the row remains textboxes, they should become edited labels